# phone number formatting in client side while entering number in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, phone-number

in my flex application i want to keep a format like...
i want to show space in client side while entering phone numbers..
After entering three numbers cursor should leave a space...

for eg:- 111 111111

is there any idea to work this in CLIENT SIDE itself

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Masked TextInput component](http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2006/11/component_masked_textinput.html). More info [is here](http://fleksray.org/adobe_flex_components_en.html#Masked%20TextInput).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to work something out using the mx:PhoneFormatter (which can be customized to match whatever pattern you'd like): http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=formatters_2.html

```
<mx:PhoneFormatter formatString="### ######" />
```

Perhaps replace the contents of the input field with the PhoneFormatted version onKeyUp.